# Relative links in Apache server

Tags: html, apache, hyperlink

I have this annoying link problem.

In an offline website there is an absolute link in an index.html file like this http://projects.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/cities-info.jpg

Now the actual file is located here: "/var/www/html/projects.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/cities-info.jpg"

Unfortunately the simple replacement of "http://" to "../" will not do the job since the link is found deep down in the website. Is there a way that I could replace "http://" to say "//" (where "//" is an Alias for the Document Root? In other words I would like to avoid spelling out the full path on every instance I need to link (/var/www/html/....).

Perhaps in the VirtualHost directive as an Alias?

Many thanks in advance!

/Paul

Answer (score 0):

In a relative URL starting with `/` will start at the document root.

If you start with `//` then that will be relative to the scheme (e.g. `http` or `https`) and you would need to specify the hostname.

You would never need to specify the file path (`/var/www/html/`) as that is handled inside the web server and is never exposed over HTTP (so HTTP clients couldn't do anything useful with it).

---

An Alias wouldn't help you. It lets you give a file a different URL. You would still need to specify that URL in the code you send to the client.

Comment: Thank you Quentin! When switching "http://" to "/" this will not display the pic in  "/var/www/html/projects.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/cities-info.jpg". What I had hoped to turn up as "localhost/projects.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/cities-info.jpg" in the browser actually shows up as "projects.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/cities-info.jpg" and does not display the picture. Maybe there is no way around this problem?

Comment: It should be `/2013/09/cities-info.jpg`. I've no idea why you are adding localhost or the full hostname.

Comment: I think we misunderstand each other. I am NOT adding "localhost" to the link in the index.html, but when the pic is displayed correctly in the browser it will read "localhost/projects.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/cities-info.jpg" in the address bar. However when I start the link with "/" (as in "/projects.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/cities-info.jpg") the address bar will display "projects.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/cities-info.jpg" (i.e. not showing "localhost") and as a result of this not displaying the picture.

Comment: I think I might have found the reason for my problem. The file "cities-info.jpg" has a reference of size attached to it "cities-info.jpg%3fw=584&h=406" which must derive from the tag src="../../../../../projects.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/cities-info.jpg%3fw=584&h=406" width="584" height="406". When the links were converted to relative links by wget, then the "href" tag was not attached with "%3fw=584&h=406" hence only reading "cities-info.jpg". This seems to be the reason to my problem since when I attach "%3fw=584&h=406" then the picture is displayed. Many thanks for your effort:-) /Paul